# How to update RStudio through installr package

Tags: r, installation, rstudio, rstudio-server

I updated my R from old to new version with the help of new package 'installr' which is quite easy and handy till date. However, i want to update RStudio in the same fashion, can anybody help me, how can this be done in installr

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Rstudio is an IDE - Integrated Development Environment for R. So if you have updated R on your computer, then there is no need to update it once again from within Rstudio.

Rstudio itself is updated as any other application - Help -> Check for updates.
Hope this helps.

Comment: So, it is not necessary to install new version of RStudio, because i have updated R. What difference then exist between new RStudio and old RStudio. At least, there must be something in it? Help> check for updates, shows that i am using lower version and new version is available

Comment: no it is not. RStudio is and IDE for R it always connects with the latest version of R that is available in your system which means if you have updated R that does not mean you have to update R Studio too. However if you update RStudio then you will get new features for RStudio which is totally independent of R version you have.